# Analysis-how to show that sequence is bounded

Tags: analysis

When we have the sequence $ a_{n}=kn-[mn]$, where $k$ and $m$ $ \in \mathbb{R} $. How could we show that the limit $ a_{n} $ exist? We have to show that the sequence is monotone and bounded,right? How can I show that it is bounded??

Comment: By $[mn]$ you mean $\lfloor mn \rfloor$?

Comment: Yes...Do I have to use the identity $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor<x<\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor+1$ ???

Comment: Are $k$ and $m$ related ? Because if you take $k=1$ and $m=0$, the sequence $a_n=n$ which is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$, $q\in{\mathbb R}$ be given and consider the sequence
$$a_n:=p\>n-\lfloor q\>n\rfloor\qquad(n\geq 0)\ .$$
I claim that the $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ does not exist unless $p=q\in{\mathbb Z}$.

When $p\ne q$ from
$$|a_n|\geq |p-q|\> n-1$$
it follows that the $a_n$ are unbounded.

When $q=p$ then $a_n$ is essentially the fractional part of $pn$.

If $p={p'\over p''}\in{\mathbb Q}$, $\ {\rm gcd}(p',p'')=1$ and $p''>1$, then this fractional part is periodic with period $p''$, and is infinitely often $=0$ and infinitely often $\geq{1\over p''}$.

When $p$ is irrational then the fractional part of ${pn}$ is equidistributed in $[0,1]$, and certainly does not converge.

There remains the case $p=q\in{\mathbb Z}$, resulting in $a_n=0$ for all $n\geq0$.